# I have this Error android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine custom titles with other title features

Tags: android

my problem is that my app works great on `Android 2.1` but when I try to `Android 4.4.2` gives me this error 
`android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You can not combine custom titles With Other title features`. I am USING ANDROID STUDIO

the error is given by the Main OnCreate:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (D) Log.e(TAG, "+++ ON CREATE +++");

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bluetooth);

    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.custom_title);


    mTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title_left_text);
    mTitle.setText(R.string.app_name);
    mTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title_right_text);


    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();


    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth is not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
        return;
    }
```

This is the error:

```
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine custom titles with other title features
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:261)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2830)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3085)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:286)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
        at com.grapeelectronic.control.Bluetooth.onCreate(Bluetooth.java:79)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: can you post you style.xml and manifest.xml code?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);` with `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE|Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);` and remove the call to `setFeatureInt`